# add new attribute on html through xslt

Tags: dita-ot

Let's say I have a ditamap file.I have published into html5.after published let's say my html file look like

```
<body id="SampleTopic">
    <h1 class="title topictitle1" id="ariaid-title1">Sample topic</h1>
    <div class="body">
        <p class="p">some<strong class="ph b">bold</strong><span class="ph special">text</span></p>
        <div class="p">
            <dl class="dl">

                    <dt class="dt dlterm">Term</dt>
                    <dd class="dd">Defination</dd>

            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

</body>
```

here in Html file, I want to add some new attribute on the body element like
`<body id="SampleTopic" class="test">`

so can anyone help me with how to solve this????
        can I add some plugin, if yes how to write the code???

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the HTML `@class` attribute, then there's no need to develop a custom plug-in.

You can just specify a value for the [`@outputclass` attribute](http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/dita/v1.3/errata02/os/complete/part1-base/langRef/attributes/commonAttributes.html) on an element in your DITA source files, and the value will be passed to the HTML `@class` attribute in the output.